# How to Updatie a uitextview from an external source.

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uitextview, swift-playground

I want to be able to update my uitextview by calling a method within my view. With this code I get a runtime error:

```
Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

If I comment out the vw.updateTerm(...) line it runs. Ultimately, I want to update a uitextview with data updated from BLE and/or http request. Any help or direction would be most appreciated.

My playground swift 3 code looks like this:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

public class TextViewController : UIViewController {

    public var textView : UITextView!

    override public func loadView() {
        textView = UITextView()
        textView.text = "Hello World!\nHello Playground!"

        self.view = textView
    }

    func updateTerm(textToUpdate: String) {
        self.textView.text.append(textToUpdate)
    }
}

let vw = TextViewController()
vw.updateTerm(textToUpdate: "here you go")

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = vw
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `loadView` is still not called at the moment when you are trying to `updateTerm`, which means that `textView` is `nil` in the `loadView` for the `vw` instance.

As far as `textView` is declared as a forced-unwrapped property, any attempt to use it while it is `nil` (as in your case) will cause a runtime error.

You should make it either a regular optional:

```
public var textView : UITextView?

override public func loadView() {
    textView = UITextView()
    textView?.text = "Hello World!\nHello Playground!"
    self.view = textView
}

func updateTerm(textToUpdate: String) {
    self.textView?.text.append(textToUpdate)
}
```

or, for example, a lazy property (if suitable in your case):

```
lazy public var textView = UITextView()

override public func loadView() {
    textView.text = "Hello World!\nHello Playground!"
    self.view = textView
}

func updateTerm(textToUpdate: String) {
    self.textView.text.append(textToUpdate)
}
```

More info can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID254).

Comment: Thanks, the link helped explain it better. I used the Lazy option which worked great for the runtime error. I added a couple of lines as follows to add to my text view, it updates, but the text never makes it to the displayed text view. [code]print(vw.textView.text)
vw.updateTerm(textToUpdate: "\nhere you go 2")
print(vw.textView.text)'code'

Comment: Added these lines of code. It appears that I have 2 instances of textView because in the playground it's appending to 1 instance but not on the one being displayed. Do I need to do something more in my class?`vw.updateTerm(textToUpdate: "\nhere you go")
print(vw.textView.text)
vw.updateTerm(textToUpdate: "\nhere you go 2")
print(vw.textView.text)`